# How to create a 64bit InstallShield Installer on a 32bit PC?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, installshield

I'm working on putting together an installer using InstallShield 2014 for an in-house developed 64bit application. My workstation is 32bit. I'm running into some warnings like the following.

```
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file Microsoft.VisualBasic, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file mscorlib, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file Oracle.DataAccess, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Core, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Data, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System.Xml, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Models.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file Microsoft.VisualBasic, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Shared.Cryptomatic.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file mscorlib, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Shared.Cryptomatic.dll
ISDEV : warning -6248: Could not find dependent file System, or one of its dependencies of component AWP.Shared.Cryptomatic.dll
```

When I check the dependencies using dependency walker on some of the files the dependency walker comes up empty.

Is it possible to create a 64bit installer on a 32bit machine? If so, what am I missing? Can someone point me in the right direction? Thank you.

EDIT: I found a possible solution at the bottom of the page for this which says to change the ".NET Scan at Build" property on the component with the warning to "Properties Only".
https://community.flexerasoftware.com/archive/index.php?t-155066.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to build a 64-bit installer on a 32-bit platform, but as you've found, dependency scanning is rougher. This is primarily due to 32-bit machines being unable to execute 64-bit code. Thus they cannot perform 64-bit COM extraction, and rarely receive 64-bit dependencies in installed form, and thus the scanning code being unable to find them.

As you indicate in your edit, you will probably have the best results by changing from dynamic approaches to static inclusion of files or registry. As part of that, it's good to turn off any COM extraction options (make sure to include the relevant registry or COM table entries) and scan-at-build options that include dependencies, such as changing *.NET Scan at Build* to **Properties Only**.

Comment: Thank you Michael!